# how to display a form within a frame using python and tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have created a notebook(file1.py) using python and tkinter. This notebook has three tabs A,B,C. I have another python file(file2.py) which contains few text fields. Now I am looking for a way to display the contents of the other file2.py  within the tab A which is in file1.py.The following is the code I used  in file1.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
# use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (300, 200, 100, 50))
root.title('test the ttk.Notebook')

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

# create a child frame for each page
f1 = tk.Frame(bg='red')
f2 = tk.Frame(bg='blue')
f3 = tk.Frame(bg='green')

# create the pages
nb.add(f1, text='A')
nb.add(f2, text='B')
nb.add(f3, text='C')

# put a button widget on child frame f1 on page1
btn1 = tk.Button(f1, text='button1')
btn1.pack(side='left', anchor='nw', padx=3, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

File2.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt
from taurus.qt.qtgui.application import TaurusApplication

app = TaurusApplication(sys.argv)
panel = Qt.QWidget()
layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
panel.setLayout(layout)

from taurus.qt.qtgui.panel import TaurusForm

panel = TaurusForm()

model = [ 'test/i1/1/%s' % p for p in props ]
panel.setModel(model)

panel.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am new to using tkinter and python so could you let me know how I could achieve it. Also in the other file(file2.py) I have few import statements like 'import sys" etc.Thanks.

Comment: what does file2.py look like? Is it importable?

Comment: I have edited my question and included the content of file2.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix those two files. One uses Tkinter, one uses PyQT. Those two libraries are incompatible with each other.